# MySQL Trigger update a 'modifiedDate' column not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, date, database-trigger

I have a special requirement where I need to automatically update a 'modifiedDate' column's datetime value to NOW(), IF:

1. Value provided is null
2. Value provided is the same as what it was before the update

BUT

If value provided is any other date string, then update column with value.

So, I've setup this trigger, but something's now quite right with it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_users_updateModDateOnUpdate` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tbl_users`
 FOR EACH ROW IF (OLD.date_modified <> NEW.date_modified) THEN
  SET NEW.date_modified = IFNULL(NEW.date_modified, NOW());
ELSE
  SET NEW.date_modified = NOW();
END IF
```

I can't see what's wrong with it... , but I'm getting strange behavior when testing with my web application.. So trying to see if the problem is with my trigger, or my php code...

Can anyone tell me if my Trigger code seems okay for my requirements above? Thanks a million!

Pat

Comment: *but I'm getting strange behavior when testing with my web application* Describe this strangeness... PS. When 'THEN' is executed the `NEW.date_modified` cannot be NULL - so IFNULL (moreover, the re-aasign itself) is excess.

Comment: PS. You should consider 5 different situations - for OLD and NEW the value may be NULL or not, and if both are not null then may be equal or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger contains an `IF` statement, so it needs at `BEGIN/END` block. Also, the conditions do not seem to do what you want. Finally, you need to set the `DELIMITER`.

I think that this does what you want:

```
delimiter //

create trigger tr_users_update_mod_date_on_update 
before update on tbl_users
for each row 
begin
    if new.date_modified is null or old.date_modified = new.date_modified then
        set new.date_modified = now();
    end if;
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Awsome. Thanks for your reply I've adopted your proposed solution and it seems to do the job. I think my previous way was okay in the end (was a php coding problem on my side), but yours is cleaner.

I'm using phpMyAdmin to manage my MySQL database and had just copied pasted the trigger from what phpMyAdmin gave me.. thus the reason it might have missed the delimiters as you mentioned. Guessing it sets it all up properly in the background, cause it works great now.

Thanks a bunch!